# Receive a ViewDidUnload message through UINavigationControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

DetailViewController <-> MasterViewController <-> ViewController

At the moment I solve my problem by having a variable in the ViewController class point to the DetailViewController so that I can perform a method when the DONE button in ViewController is pressed.

```
- (void)doneButtonPressed { 
       [self.detailViewController method];
}
```

What I want to do is to have the ViewController report to DetailViewController when it unloads, so that DetailViewController can perform the method itself.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
      [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
      [[self.navigationController delegate] performSelector:@selector(method)];
}
```

What I have tried is to have the MasterViewController set the ViewControllers delegate to DetailViewController with this code, when it is pushed:

```
ViewController *ViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

ViewController.navigationController.delegate = self.detailViewController;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:ViewController animated:YES];
```

UINavigationControllerDelegate has been set in DetailViewController.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question was badly formulated.

The answer is in the documentation:

- View Controller Programming Guide for iOS

  -> Modal View Controllers

  - Dismissing a Modal View Controller

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW14

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. If you believe the question was badly worded, feel free to edit and improve it so that other users with the same issue can find it easier and benefit from the solution you found. Welcome to Stack Overflow!